# Sunspot - How to use StatsComponent with excluding filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have used Sunspot for my website searching and filtering. I have also price slider on my website. Sunspot provide me stats for price columns but with filters. I want to exclude the price filters from stats. Otherwise stats will generate on filtered results.

I have got same issue which was mentioned below JIRA link.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3177

*It would be useful to exclude the effects of some "fq" params from the set of documents used to compute stats – similar to 
how you can exclude tagged filters when generating facet counts...
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters*

So this was already implemented into SOLR. But I am not able to understand, how I can do same with Sunspot. Can any one help me for same?

Thanks